# Looking for keywords within column of longer phrases

Tags: excel-formula

If a keyword on Sheet 1 is **contained within a cell** in a column on Sheet 2, I want to copy the value in another column in Sheet 2. How can I do this? I have tried `VLookUp` and other but without success as they only work when the keyword **exactly matches** the target cell.

```
Sheet 1
╔═══╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║   ║     A     ║    B     ║
╠═══╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1 ║ Horse     ║ Winnings ║
║ 2 ║ Shadowfax ║          ║ < should show $9000
║ 3 ║ Telefax   ║          ║ < should show $0
║ 4 ║ Ceefax    ║          ║ < should show $660
╚═══╩═══════════╩══════════╝

Sheet 2
╔═══╦══════════════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║   ║                A                 ║    B     ║
╠═══╬══════════════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 1 ║ Race                             ║ Winnings ║
║ 2 ║ Ascot, Ed, 2014-06-10            ║ $50      ║
║ 3 ║ Goodwood, Shergar, 2016-05-11    ║ $80      ║
║ 4 ║ Doncaster, Shadowfax, 2015-06-30 ║ $9000    ║
║ 5 ║ Goodwood, Ceefax, 2016-07-21     ║ $660     ║
╚═══╩══════════════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: can you share the values?

Comment: Hi yes there horses names in sheet1 C6, but sheet2 B2 is location, where it ran and the name all in the one cell and what I wont to get is the lay odds in G2. Hope that makes sence

Comment: it sound like you are trying to find a value in an array and than doing off set : check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948175/excel-find-a-value-in-an-array-and-return-the-contents-of-the-corresponding-co

Comment: how would I change it soo it looks for the keyword from sheet2 and also the value, as it wont be at the top

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards (the `*` character) in Excel formula string comparison.

Try a basic `Index-Match`:

```
In Sheet 1 B2:
=Index('Sheet 2'!B:B, Match("*" & A2 & "*", 'Sheet 2'!A:A, 0))
```

Or `SumIfs` to add up what's in `'Sheet 2'!B:B` if there's more than one value per input on Sheet 1.

```
=SumIfs('Sheet 2'!B:B, `Sheet 2`!A:A, "*" & A2 & "*" )
```