# Excel formula: find cell value in another sheet and return the header of the column it's in

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of names in one excel sheet and in another sheet I have many columns with column headers, and the names underneath.

So let's say in sheet "raw" i have the name "Mike".

In another sheet, there is somewhere a column with the header "Consumer" and a list of names under it (including the name Mike).  I want a formula to pull the header "Consumer" in the "raw" sheet.  I can't transpose and do a regular vlookup because I have a long list of names and each column has a different number of names under the headers.

Any advice on what formula I can use instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `INDEX/MATCH`, it works with both vertical and horizontal data.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly needs to be done? Is the header "Consumer" in both raw sheet as well as the other sheet? It would be nice if you could post some images of the different sheets to help us out.

Comment: This question and answer will probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948175/excel-find-a-value-in-an-array-and-return-the-contents-of-the-corresponding-co

Comment: can you post some screenshots of your excel sheets, and also how you want the data to be displayed as an example?

Answer (score 0):

If my second sheet was named `Data` and set up like this:

[image]

I would use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Data!1:1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(Data!$B$2:$L$17)/(Data!$B$2:$L$17=A1),1))
```

To get

[image]