# Excel: Find Value Underneath text with HLOOKUP in a Range defined as a Formula

Tags: excel, reference, match

[image]

In the defined range (red rectangle) I'm trying to find the Value (text) underlined green and then have the value underneath it read out. This is part of getting all the values of the unstructured table into another structured table.

**Main Goal is it to get the text in a predefined range, which is defined by searching for the first and the second component which in this case is "Pack" and "PET" the next would be "PET" and "Orange" and so on. paired with searching for the different rounds like 0 and 1 So I'll get exactly the red square but for every component in each round**

Best attempt so far:

```
=INDEX(purchasing!B1:B17,MATCH("Lower bound (weeks)",purchasing!B1:B17,0)+1,1)
```

but how do i get the range from the other table which is calculated by a formula into where B1:B17 stands? Indirect wouldn't do it, but why? used it for a lot of other very similar tasks where array-table was asked. here it is array, can a convert it somehow?

```
INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&ranges!B2)
```

Using the Formula:

```
=HLOOKUP("Lower bound (weeks)",A1:E17,2,FALSE)
```

gives me #N/A
While:

```
=LOOKUP("Lower bound (weeks)",A1:E17)
```

gives me the result: Delivery window

third try was this formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:E17,MATCH("Lower bound (weeks)",A1:E17,0)+1,1)
```

again only an #N/A, the only formula giving me the right result would be:

```
=INDEX(B1:B17,MATCH("Lower bound (weeks)",B1:B17,0)+1,1)
```

but then this is not the range i figured out by formula in another table. So i don't know this range in advance why i tried to do it with offset. Also gave me a wrong result because Offsets sets off the position of the cell and not of the value in it.

The Formula for the Offset in the other table is:

```
=VLOOKUP("contract index",INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&ranges!B2),2,FALSE)
```

and then in the table ranges!B2 it is:

```
=G4&":"&H5
```

which gets the single values of the serached terms Pack, PET, Orange and so on

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH($O4,INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&G$3),0),MATCH(G$2,purchasing!$1:$1,0)-1,4)
=ADDRESS(MATCH($O5,INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&H$3),0),MATCH(H$2,purchasing!$1:$1,0)-1,4)
```

Any way around this issue?

The Ranges table which contains all the ranges where it should search for the text and if it is there give me the number underneath. All the ranges are searched automatically by a formula

[image]

Formula in B2

```
=G4&":"&H5
```

Formula in G2

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH($O4,INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&G$3),0),MATCH(G$2,purchasing!$1:$1,0)-1,4)
```

Formula in G12

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(G4&"1"))+1,4),"1","")&SUBSTITUTE(G4,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(G$2,purchasing!$1:$1,0)-1,4),"1",""),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following Formula in the final sheet in cell R2 to resolve my issue:

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&TEXT(ranges!G12,"")),MATCH("Lower bound (weeks)",INDIRECT("purchasing!"&TEXT(ranges!G12,"")),0)+1,1)),"NULL",INDEX(INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&TEXT(ranges!G12,"")),MATCH("Lower bound (weeks)",INDIRECT("purchasing!"&TEXT(ranges!G12,"")),0)+1,1))
```

[image]

this formula points to the sheet you seen on the picture underneath to cell G12 with the value of B2:B17 in it. Formula to get the Range of B2:B17 is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(G4&"1"))+1,4),"1","")&SUBSTITUTE(G4,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(G$2,purchasing!$1:$1,0)-1,4),"1",""),"")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(G5&"1"))+1,4),"1","")&SUBSTITUTE(G5,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(G$2,purchasing!$1:$1,0)-1,4),"1",""),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
=INDEX(A1:E17,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Lower bound (weeks)",A1:E17))),ROW(1:17),99^99),1)+1,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Lower bound (weeks)",A1:E17))),COLUMN(A:E),99^99),1))
```

Enter as an array formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

This returns the row where found and adds one to it

```
SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Lower bound (weeks)",A1:E17))),ROW(1:17),99^99),1)+1
```

This returns the column where found:

```
SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Lower bound (weeks)",A1:E17))),COLUMN(A:E),99^99),1)
```

And then you use these for the intersect on the range indexed with

```
INDEX(A1:E17,.......)
```

Reference:

[Excel - Find a value in an array and return the contents of the corresponding column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948175/excel-find-a-value-in-an-array-and-return-the-contents-of-the-corresponding-co)

Comment: So if i do it like that, i have to replace all the A1:E17 with the values from my range table and then what am i gonna do about the ROW(1:17)? Isn't this solution going to use a lot of computer ressources as it has ranges for thousand of cells even if my shet is going from row 1 - 108 and then from cell 1 to approx 50?

Comment: Give it a try and report back :-)

Comment: I was working with the example you gave. Excel should still be fine with the dimensions you specify.  You could also use a dynamic named range and substitute that into the formula though you need a way to return the columns array to match. I don't think you will have a problem but you can always shift to a vba solution.

Comment: As soon as I change the first A1:A17 to INDIRECT(ranges!B2) it doesn't work anymore

Comment: So you are now changing the question? What is the purpose of the indirect? It won't return the range object you need for the Index.

Comment: Wait I'll ad a picture of the ranges i have to make the original question clearer. Because i have a lot of ranges to get a value out of not only 1 so i don't wanna do it manually but rather by looking the ranges up which i posted above with the other formulas i provided

Comment: Ummm okay..... :-) Definitely re-work the question because for the methods you have tried the solution I have given is pretty much the standard way to do it.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to put it another way because I'm so into the problem I'm facing can't see the trees anymore -.- I just want to search for a specific text in a predefined Range and if it is there get the value underneath. The predefined Range is defined by searching for the first "Pack" and the first "PET" and then for in between PET and Orange and so on.

Comment: Changed the answer slightly to try to explain clearer what i mean and what the main goal is of this sheet

Comment: I would suggest that you now have two questions one of which I have answered. The finding of the ranges via the locating of the different ranges is more involved and I am starting to lean towards a VBA solution for that as one could use Find and Find Next using row of first find.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time with that but I'm feeling more than uncomfortable with VBA solutions as i did a lot of them and they were always inconsistent and weak. Look at my last edit i almost have it. i just need a way to get a placeholder for this 1 variable!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167831/discussion-between-qharr-and-j-doe).